# tcl/tk on mac os, Python IDLE won't start and Macport not working properly

Tags: tcl, macports

I really need someone's help here.

Early, I was playing around with homebrew, macport and active state TCL/TK after I got the new mac pro. But somehow  I accidentally deleted the tcl/tclsh folder when I was trying to delete the active state version of tcl.

Now the problem is when I'm trying to install MongoDB with Macport using:

sudo port install mongodb

It give me an error says:[image]

so I guess I delete the wrong file..is there any way I can get it back? I tried install tcl/tk using active state package but didn't work.

Help really needed...!
Thanks

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix Homebrew and MacPorts. But I don't think that's your problem here.

Comment: Also, this problem has nothing to do with mongodb; you've broken MacPorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you've deleted (at least part of) the *system* Tcl/Tk pre-installed by Apple.* MacPorts explicitly uses Apple's Tcl (or its own, if you ask it, but not ActiveState's or Homebrew's or any other). That's why it's looking for `/usr/bin/tclsh` rather than just whatever `tclsh` is on the PATH.

If you dig inside the Mountain Lion installer package, you may be able to find and run the Tcl/Tk installer manually, but Apple makes that different (and harder) with each release. The easier thing to do is just run the installer and let it repair things for you.

---

* It's also possible that you first *replaced* parts of Apple's Tcl with another version, which you shouldn't have done, and then broke that other version. But the solution is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna go ahead with your first suggestion. Dig into Mountain Lion installer package folder and try to repair it. Any hints? Thanks again!

Comment: @IanZhao: IIRC, the packages are all inside an .mpkg somewhere in the .app bundle, so something like `'find "/Volumes/Install/Install Mountain Lion.app" -name '*.pkg'` should find them, and the names are pretty obvious. But I'm not sure that's right for 10.8 re-install disks, and I can't check. (The only machines I've bought since 10.8 didn't come with any disks… which I guess makes sense, since none of them have a DVD drive…) If you get lost, maybe open a new question (although superuser.com may be a better place than here)…

Comment: Thank you so much! is this 'find "/Volumes/Install/Install Mountain Lion.app" -name '*.pkg' should be ran in Terminal?

Comment: @IanZhao: Yes. And you have to replace the path with the actual path to the installer app. (You can drag it from the Finder to the Terminal window to automatically paste in the path if you don't know how to do it manually.)